# PowerBI DAX Calculation: moving average group calculation by month

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table, and I want to calculate the average sales based on a country and a channel but the average moves by monthly:
[image: Sales by Country, Channel and Period]

So for the first Average Sales only considers 202001, then the second one will for 202001 and 202002, and so on. The final output is Average Sales. Here sales is a measure created. Now I have the period until 202003, later I may have April, May, etc.My question is how to calculate Average Sales. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Create a calculated column and use the following DAX formula:

```
Average Sales = 
VAR __country = 'Table'[Country]
VAR __period = 'Table'[Period]
VAR __subTable = FILTER( 'Table', 'Table'[Country] = __country && 'Table'[Period] < __period + 1)

Return CALCULATE(  AVERAGE('Table'[Sales], __subTable )
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful response. 1) I have trouble finding the string Country, Period, and Channel in the process of defining variables. In the list of the table, I only see integer columns, decimal columns and measures. Also 2) In the final return part, Sales is a measure calculated by other columns, so 'Table'[Sales]  will not be shown up in the list.  Thanks.